# How do I adapt my ggplot code in order to change the default colours used in the chart produced?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts, colors

I do not like the colors in my chart that the code below produces.

How do I adapt the code, in order to change the array of colors used within the chart?

```
ggplot(Rating, aes(x = Function, y = Freq, fill = Rating)) + 
  ggtitle("Test")  + 
  labs(x="Function", y = "Rating") +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Hello Jed, welcom to SO. You will certainly attract more people to look at your question, if you deliver a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). You will find solutions to your question at many places, one could be [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually)

Comment: You might find it useful to look at the `scale_fill_*()` functions, for example `scale_fill_distiller()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a general question, so there are quite a few answers, here.  Generally, you change the colors used in the plot via one of the `scale_*_**` functions, where `*` is the aesthetic (`color`, `fill`, etc), and `**` is the type or method for creating the scale.  Some of these include:

- `manual` for manually defining stuff
- `brewer` to use one of the predefined [Brewer color palettes](https://colorbrewer2.org/)
- `discrete` for discrete scales
- `gradient`, `gradient2` or `gradientn` to define color gradients (you give some set number of colors and a gradient is created to apply to a continuous variable for the aesthetic).
- `viridis` to use the viridis scales.  There are discrete and continuous versions here, so you typically need to specify
- and many others... like `distiller`, `fermenter`, and various others that come with `RColorBrewer`.

Here's some examples below to get you started.  Here's a default plot:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(carb), y=mpg)) + geom_col(aes(fill=factor(carb)))
p
```

[image]

**Example applying one of the Brewer scales**:

```
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette='Set1')
```

[image]

**Example using a viridis scale:**

```
p + scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[image]

**Example using a manually-defined scale:**  Note here you specify using `scale_fill_manual(values=...)`.  The `values=` argument must be sent a vector or list of colors which are *at least* the same number as the number of levels for your variable assigned to the `fill=` aesthetic.  You can also pass a named vector to explicitly define *which* color is applied to individual factor levels.  Here I'm just showing you the lovely colors of the rainbow:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values=rainbow(6))
```

[image]